# Best way to implement jQuery click functions

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML code that is created dynamically and includes potentially dozens of anchors.  I want to add a click handler to each anchor and I can think of a number of different ways but don't know which one to choose.  Assuming the anchors have a class of "myclass" and the code executed when clicked is the same for each.

**Method 1**

```
$(document).delegate(".myclass", "click", function() {
  // Do some work
});
```

**Method 2:**

```
var $a = $("<a href='#' class='myclass'>Text</a>");
$a.bind("click", function() {
  // Do some work
});
```

**Method 3:**

```
function clickHandler() {
  // Do some work
}

var $a = $("<a href='#' class='myclass'>Text</a>");
$a.bind("click", function() {
  clickHandler();
});
```

I like Method 2 as the handler code is right where the anchor is created and added to the DOM but if I have lots of these anchors then will JavaScript effectively create dozens of separate functions or is it clever enough to use just one?

Comment: Actually, I think `delegate` has been deprecated anyway.  I think it's `on` now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `delegate` replaces `live` as of jQuery 1.7 whereas `on` will replace `bind`.

Comment: from api.jQuery.com: "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is some container which contains all of these anchors and you're using jQuery 1.7 or above then the best solution is the `on` API

```
$('#theContainer').on('click', 'a.myclass', function() {
  // Click Handler
});
```

Note: Make sure to choose the container which is closest to the location where the anchors live.  This increases the efficiency of the search to find them on the event fire.

Comment: I think it is important to note also, bind as close down the DOM to where your elements are, as every time the event fires, jQuery will need to search for all the nodes that match it.

Answer (score 2):

Method 2 is better is you don't need to have 'live' event (ie adding element in the DOM after you bind the event).

But with jQuery 1.7, you have 'on' to bind event.

Comment: I believe you meant jQuery 1.7 not 1.9

Answer (score 2):

With `.on()` there is a way where you can add one event listener to a `div`. So you would have one event listener on the div where all of your anchors are placed:

```
$('#navigation').on('click', 'a.myclass', function() {
  //Handler
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
  official documentation. This brings you more effiency. Maybe you should also check out the http://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/ course. Jeffrey Way explains that in simple examples which are good to understand and easy.

Comment: I like the "on" keyword (new to me!). Just as long as the parent works for all elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use `live`

```
$(".myClass").live("click", clickHandler);
```

Live also adds the event handler to newly created elements.

**Edit:**
use `on` instead, if you're using jquery 1.7:

```
$(".myClass").on("click", clickHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myclass').click(function() {
    // do something
});
```

This should cover all bases.

As far as I am aware it should create a separate instance per control, but it is totally OO so should be pretty efficient.

To address the "not if the links are dynamically added" point:

```
$('.myclass').unbind('click').click(function() {
    clickHandler();
});
```

Of course this needs to be re-run each time more HTML is dynamically added, but that is the same for every solution listed here.

Comment: Not if the elements are dynamically added.

Comment: This is not useful, because when the elements are added dynamically the events do not get fired !

Comment: Wrong EvilP - see the second part

Comment: Why the downvote? If there is a valid reason why this won't work, I'll delete the answer.